# Get amount of rows in a database that have a certain value? - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to get the amount of rows from a database that have certain values? Say I want to show how many people there are in a database that voted for guy 1. It would say `People that voted for guy 1: <number>` **(In the database the choice of guy 1 or 2 is stored as either 0 or 1.)**

I tried

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE choice=1`

Didn't work. Any other ways?

**EDIT:**

Full code:

`$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE choice=1";
 $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
 $result0 = $stmt->num_rows();
 echo $result0;`

I got 0 when there were specifically 2 that were in the database

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  It has to work. What are the fields in your table, can a user vote more than once?

Comment: What did you get? What did you expect? But we have to know your example data. As @developerwjk said: your query should work.

Comment: I assume your query works, but doesn't return the correct results?  If that's the case, if you want the # of votes for a specific person, why does your `where` criteria look for `vote=1`?  That will just tell you the # of records where vote = 1...  Shouldn't it look for `where guy = 1`?

Comment: @sgeddes It has to be vote=1 because that's what it is name in the database.

Comment: @VMai I expected a number, like 20. I updated the code so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you `select` the number of rows matching the predicate `choice=1`:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE choice=1";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
```

Then, you ask the number of returned rows for that query:

```
$result0 = $stmt->num_rows();
echo $result0;
```

However, since the query returns a number of rows, it should only contains 1 row containing that value. What you want is to either change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM vote WHERE choice=1
```

and get the returned number of rows almost as you did, or retrieve the value in the first row you get from your original query:

```
$result0 = $stmt->bind_result($result0);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Note however that:

- `num_rows` is not a function, it's a property of `$stmt`,
- you should use the `store_result()` method on `$stmt` before accessing `num_rows` to get a meaningful result

So the code using `num_rows` should be like:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$result0 = $stmt->num_rows;
echo $result0;
```

(see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)).

Comment: Works, I just needed to put `$stmt->store_result();` before the `num_rows`

Answer (score -2):

I think you can try this :

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM highscores WHERE vote='1'

Comment: Just added quatations? I don't think so because 1 is a numeric character